# Unable to assert sharedpreference data

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, sharedpreferences

I am writing Junit test for shared preference but when I add fields into it and try to retrieve stored fields then it fails.

Junit Code

```
@Test
    fun `when store user then load user`() {
        whenever(context.getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).thenReturn(userPrefs)
        whenever(userPrefs.edit()).thenReturn(editor)
        doNothing().`when`(editor).apply()
        val user = getUser()
        whenever(editor.putString(USER_PREFS, user!!.userID)).thenReturn(editor)
        assert(userPrefs.contains(USER_ID_KEY))
    }
```

Error

> Assertion failed java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed

Please help me to know if I make any mistake.

Comment: Hi! After looking at your last three questions I'd like to ask you: what is the purpose of testing the Android framework implementations, like SharedPreferences in your case. By me you should rather be interested in testing your own implementations, isn't it?

Comment: Intent is not to test android framework components but stuffs are related to it. I have shared excerpt of my usecase for which start is to make sharedpreferences mocking working properly.

Comment: First, you aren't mocking it properly. Second, in most cases you won't be able to mock the framework implementations...For testing the framework related stuff you are to separate it from your code base with interfaces and test their implementations. E.g. create `Preferences` interface and `PreferencesImpl` implementation that deals with the framework stuff. Now mocking and testing `Preferences` becomes easier and framework independent.